# Background color not changing in Google Chrome even after running "npm run dev" command in integrated terminal of VS Code

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, google-chrome, visual-studio-code

I am learning Laravel.
I tried to change the background color of web page. The course suggested to run -> "npm run dev" command in integrated terminal of Visual studio code which I indeed run to get a "Build successful" message. However, the background color still remains the same.
Also, I run npm install dev, npm install webpack --save, npm install --ignore-platform-reqs , npm install --dev.
However, nothing changes and the background color still remains same.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: *How* did you try changing the background color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try clearing browser cache by hitting CTRL+F5 in the browser while viewing the page.

Comment: Why downvoted? This might be the problem... Rebuilding a project does not clear cache in browsers... unless some version control, or advanced caching takes place...

Comment: I didn't down voted. Thank you so much. Cleared the cache and now it's working fine. :-)

Comment: No, it was someone else that didn't like the simplicity in my answer I guess.. Glad I could help!